# Operating System, C and process memory allocation

Tags: c, process, operating-system

We say that global variables and static variables are always initialized to 0. Then my question is, why do we have separate sections in a binary for initialized and uninitialized data.

I wrote the following code -

```
int i;
int j=0;
static int k;
static int l=0;

int main()
{
  static int m=0;
  static int n;
    printf("%d, %d\n",i,j);
    printf("%d, %d\n",k,l);
    printf("%d, %d\n",m,n);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output was -

```
0, 0
0, 0
0, 0
```

I checked output of objdump of bss section and only this section contained the variables. But as per the link -

> http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_memory_and_heaps.html
>
> Typically, in each process, the virtual memory available to that
>   process is called its address space. Each process's address space is
>   typically organized in 6 sections that are illustrated in the next
>   picture: environment section - used to store environment variables and
>   command line arguments; the stack, used to store memory for function
>   arguments, return values, and automatic variables; the heap (free
>   store) used for dynamic allocation, two data sections (for initialized
>   and uninitialized static and global variables) and a text section
>   where the actual code is kept.

So, I am just confused. If we have two data sections why is all the data placed in .bss section. And also I wanna understand what does .data contain.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: The `.bss` section is 'stored' in the binary as a length (and section header); it doesn't need to explicitly store zeroes.  For structures with non-zero elements, the initialized values are stored in the `.data` section.  In many modern compilers, constant strings are stored in the `.text` section, though traditionally they would have been non-constant and stored in the `.data` section.  That requires a fairly old definition for 'traditionally', but before the C89 standard, C compilers generally did not support read-only constant strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .data section is typically reserved for variables with values known at compile time or larger blocks of constant memory such as strings that are known at compile time and static array blocks. Also the .bss section stores unintialized or zero valued variables because storing zero'es in the .data section wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: So basically this means that even if i initialize a global variable with 0, it is stored in .bss. I verified the same and once i initalize a variable with some other value it is moved to .data. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yeah it would be kind of odd if in .data you had some metadata that just had a bunch of 0 blocks taking up space.